# how to dynamically refreshing an item (ideally bages) in Twitter's Bootstrap fixed navbar?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I am using twitter boostrap fixed navbar. I am trying to refresh (pulling every so often using javascript refresh function) one of the menuitem of the navbar (ideally refreshing a twitter badge that is associated with this menuitem,  e.g "Email 10", here the badge is "10" and would like to refresh it to show, for this example, the number of unread emails. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Give it a unique id:

```
<span class="badge badge-important" id="email-count">6</span>
```

In your javascript code, use jQuery to select it and set the number:

```
$("#email-count").text(emails);
```